# Is there a way to force HTML <a> break line and not be displayed full width?

Tags: html, css

I have HTML code that goes like this:

```css
.container a.source {
    align-self: flex-start;
    }

.container p {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<p>
<a href="#" class="source">looooooooooong</a>
<a href="#" class="source">mediumish</a>
<a href="#" class="source">short</a>
Text here <a href="#">link with no class</a> more text.
</p>
</div>
```

By default, links will be displayed inline, but I want them to start from a new line.

- I can easily place a `<br>` tag after each link but would prefer not to.
- `display: block` would make the links take up the whole width.
- `inline-block` would display links next to each other which is not what I want.
- `display: table-row`. It's a better option than `display: block`, but different shorter links would take the same length as the longest of them.
- CSS `display: table-cell` looks great, but not when there is more than one link since they will be displayed next to each other.

Is there a way to force each link with a class to:

1. Start from a new line.
2. Have individual length.
3. Do this without altering HTML?

A solution was offered:

```css
a {
  align-self: flex-start
}

p {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

The links are displayed just as I want them to. Problem is that other links are displayed in a similar manner, which is not desired.

Comment: Why wouldn't you prefer to add a `<br>`? I don't understand

Comment: Are you trying `display: inline-block`?

Comment: It would take the whole width of its parent container if it was `display: block`. If it breaks the line, that's what it does anyway...

Comment: Adding a <br> isn't good for accessibility.

Comment: @nghiepit Definitely not `display: inline-block`, it will display my links next to ack other when I need them to be displayed each on a new line.

Comment: @Ath.Bar. This is not very flexible since I will have to alter the HTML. And it appears that this isn't good for accessibility.

Comment: @HereticMonkey But is it possible to make it not take the whole width?

Comment: Sure, set a width on the anchor. `a { display:block; width: 50%; }` would cause it to take half the width of its parent container.

Comment: @HereticMonkey And it would take exactly half of the parent container. Is it possible to make the links end where the text of the link ends and still display every link on a new line?

Answer (score 3):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
a {
  background: pink;
  align-self: flex-start
}

a:hover {
  background: green;
}

p {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="#">link long variety</a>
  <a href="#">link</a>
  <a href="#">link</a> Text here
</p>
```

Comment: Links would take up the whole width.

Comment: I have no idea what that means....the links are as long as they need to be and no more.

Comment: Add a `:hover` style to prove the anchors are not affected when the mouse goes over the space to the right of the anchor.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I was applying flex to the wrong element. However, it now affects other links with the text. I've edited my snippet to demonstrate. But however it may seem, I'm not creating problems intentionally.

Answer (score 2):

This is your goal?

```css
.link-list {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
};
```

```html
<p class="link-list">
<a>link</a>
<a>link</a>
<a>link</a>
Text here
</p>
```

Comment: Not really. It gives the same result as `display: block`. If I hover the mouse on an empty area to the other side of the page, the link will be there. I don't need my links to take the whole width. And it breaks the display of `:before` pseudo element. that is not displayed in the example since it's not related.

Answer (score 1):

You could use block and set a max-with to avoid using the whole width.

```css
a{
  display: block;
  max-width: 100px;
  }
```

```html
        <a>link</a>
        <a>link</a>
        <a>link</a>
        <p>Text here</p>
```

Comment: This is the best one so far. But my each of my links has a different number of characters. Setting `max-width` extends shorter links to the end of the longest one.

Answer (score -1):

Another approach (a very old one, from days *loooooooooong* before **CSS Flexbox** and **CSS Grid** arrived on the scene...):

Combine the following:

- `display: inline-block`
- `float: left`
- `clear: left`

---

**Working Example:**

```css
a {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
clear: left;
margin-bottom: 2px;
padding: 6px;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<p>
<a>loooooooooongLink</a>
<a>mediumLink</a>
<a>shorty</a>
</p>
```